# LyX / LyZ / Zotero Refer to remote BibTex file located on dropbox folder

Tags: biblatex, online, zotero

Does anyone know if there is any way of using `\addbibresource` pointing to remote files located on a Dropbox server and refered to by the unique Dropbox location link like:

```
\addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1x0l95hbcypij/TestBibliography.bib?dl=1}
```

So far for me it does not work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863/), they'll be marked as code, like in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). And usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Answer (score 4):

Does the url you use return a `.bib` file? If so, it should work. If it needs a login/password, you'll need to supply these in the url or use environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but you have to use the correct link.

Dropbox creates a link to a webpage where you can download the file. To get the link to the actual file you need to copy the link to which the `Download` button leads.
The resulting link is much longer, and when inputted in a browser it will immediately (ask you to) download the `.bib` file instead of presenting the Dropbox page first.

You should use that long link in the `addbibresource` command.